# Redirect output processed via vbscript (cscript) to file

Tags: vbscript, command, timestamp, ping, wsh

Issue with command output:

I am attempting to have a continuous ping report back to a text file.

Started with:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -t >> C:Textping.txt
```

Works great

I also want to have timestamps listed before each ping

So Wrote:

```
Dim str
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
  str = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine now &amp; " - " &amp; str
Loop
```

Saved it as timestampLog.vbs on my desktop and dropped a copy into my system 32 folder.

Put all of this into a batch file:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -t | cscript //nologo timestamplog.vbs >> C:Pingtest1.txt
```

It works perfectly except that the output is printing to command prompt and Pingtest1.txt while created by the batch file is empty.

Can someone please assist me with getting the output to Pingtest1.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running it with cscript, and writing output to **STDERR** (using `WScript.StdErr.WriteLine`). So you could use:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -t | cscript //nologo timestamplog.vbs 2> C:/Pingtest1.txt
                                                      ^^
```

`>` denotes **STDOUT**, `2>` denotes **STDERR**.