# Using cscript to output "ipconfig /all" but text file is blank

Tags: vbscript, io-redirection, wsh

I am trying to pull `ipconfig /all` output and put it into a text file.  I have created a small VBScript that runs `ipconfig` without issues.  Then I call it in another VBScript.  All of this runs, but the output text file remains empty and the primary VBScript doesn't seem to write anything after the `ipconfig.vbs` runs.

Here is the sample from the primary .vbs script:

```
' Pulling network config
Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt", 8)
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt")
objShell.Run("cscript //nologo C:\Users\dsadmin\Downloads\ipconfig.vbs >C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt")
```

Here is the script it calls (ipconfig.vbs):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("ipconfig /all")
```

I'm out of ideas when it comes to shuffling things around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect output processed via vbscript (cscript) to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572252/redirect-output-processed-via-vbscript-cscript-to-file)

Comment: You not passing anything back to the Standard Output Stream, use `.Exec()` to access the `.StdOut` stream.

Comment: @Lankymart You mean use "objShell.Exec" instead of "objShell.Run"?  When I do that, it still fails to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with that approach

1. As [@Ansgar-Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42112358/692942) the `>` redirection is part of CMD.
2. Once the redirection is working you have to retrieve the Standard Output from the executed command and redirect it to the `cscript.exe` output. Unfortunately `.Run()` doesn't provide access to the Standard Output Stream you have to use `.Exec()` instead.

Here is an example *(assumes all files in same direction, but can be modified)*;

```
' Pulling network config
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c cscript //nologo ipconfig.vbs > network_config.txt")
```

in the ipconfig.vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set exec = objShell.Exec("ipconfig /all")
'Redirect output from executed command to the script output.
Call WScript.StdOut.Write(exec.StdOut.ReadAll)
```

Output in network_config.txt

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
...
```

*<sup><sup>...</sup> Truncated for readability and sensitive data removed</sup>*

Comment: This works!  Excellent.  Thank you so much!  Now, if you wouldn't mind pass on a bit of knowledge to a beginner, I have a couple questions that will hopefully help me avoid this problem in the future.

It's not clear to me what the "%COMSPEC%" string does.  Is there a simple explanation to be had?

Secondly - with regards to the "ipconfig.vbs" - how does "set exec" allow output as opposed to "obj.ShellRun" ?

Comment: @wyatt8919 to be perfectly honest it's a lot of work for not a lot of gain, Ansgars suggestion to run it directly should work with less complexity. **Edit:** Although I've just tested it and it's failing for me, will investigate...thought to be honest that should work.

Comment: I did try, but doing it his way gives me a "handle is invalid" error.

Comment: @wyatt8919 I got the same but realised it's still calling `ipconfig.vbs` because it exists in the current directory even though we call `ipconfig` without the `.vbs` extension, just rename your `ipconfig.vbs` file and it will work.

Comment: @wyatt8919 `%COMSPEC%` is a Windows environment variable holding the full path to `cmd.exe`. The `Exec()` method provides you with an object that gives you access to the standard file descriptors of the spawned process. The `Run` method doesn't do that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers still, `objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig /all > network_config.txt"` is far simplier then this.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Got it.  I think I understand.  Thank you for the explanation.  I am trying to follow Lankymart's explanation, but I'm not sure I'm getting it fully.  Is there a way to avoid using two different scripts here by using your method?

Comment: By running `objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig /all > network_config.txt"` from your primary script you won't need a second script. I thought that was rather obvious.

Comment: @wyatt8919 What part are you not following? When testing Ansgars second method *(which I'd recommend by the way)* the command `objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig /all > network_config.txt"` fails because the previous VBS file you are using called `ipconfig.vbs` is still in the directory, so the CMD assumes you want to execute that not the built-in `ipconfig` command. Just rename `ipconfig.vbs` to `ipconfig1.vbs` and it will work.

Comment: @Lankymart I apologize but you're going to have to really break it down for me because this is all new.  How does renaming this help?  Isn't the idea to avoid running a second script?  Why is the CMD assuming that ipconfig is actually "ipconfig.vbs" when it's no longer in the script?

Comment: @wyatt8919 this is just happening because of the order in which you have tried things. You had a script called `ipconfig.vbs` when you were first testing the method, correct? You don't need it now but it's still there, so when you execute your primary script and call `ipconfig /all` because there is a file in that directory with the same name *(but different extension)* it assumes you want to run that and because the `ipconfig.vbs` doesn't understand the `>` redirection it throws an error `Handle is Invalid`. By renaming the file you stop it being called accidently.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection (`>`) is a CMD builtin feature. You need to run the statement in CMD to be able to use it:

```
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c cscript //NoLogo C:\ipconfig.vbs >C:\network_config.txt"
```

Of course you need to ensure that the second script writes to STDOUT in the first place, as [@Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42112671/1630171) pointed out.

If all your second script does is running `ipconfig /all` there's not much point in wrapping that in a separate script, though. Just run it directly:

```
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig /all >C:\network_config.txt"
```

Comment: Alright, I replaced 

`objShell.run("cscript //nologo C:\Users\dsadmin\Downloads\ipconfig.vbs >C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt")`

with 

`objShell.run("cscript //nologo C:\Users\dsadmin\Downloads\ipconfig.vbs >C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt")`

and I now get a "invalid character" error.  Do I need parentheses somewhere?

Comment: The first example will not work without also redirecting the Standard Output Stream in `ipconfig.vbs`.

Comment: @wyatt8919 You replaced a statement with the exact same statement, and now you're getting an error? I somehow doubt that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm sorry but that does seem to be what's happening.  I'm using this statement exactly: `objShell.run "%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig /all > C:\Users\dsadmin\Desktop\LogNet\network_config.txt"` and I keep getting the handle error

Comment: @wyatt8919 as I've said three or four times now, it's because where the primary script is running you have a file called `ipconfig.vbs` so it runs that instead of the in-built `ipconfig` command *(assumes because they have the same name they are the same, ignores extension)*. Just rename the `ipconfig.vbs` to something else or move it out of the primary script directory to stop the script being executed by default.

Comment: @Lankymart Alright alright alright.  I'm dumb.  I see what everyone is trying to tell me now.  I deleted the `ipconfig.vbs` and it worked.  Didn't realize that CMD assuming things would get me into trouble.  Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @wyatt8919 we got there in the end. Glad it's now working for you.